# Free strict Picard groupoid

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Suppose that $S$ is a set and that $\mathcal G(S)$ is a strict Picard groupoid endowed with a function $f\colon S \to \mathrm{ob}\mathcal G(S)$. For any other strict Picard groupoid $\mathcal G$, restriction along $f$ gives a functor
$$
\mathrm{Fun}^\otimes(\mathcal G(S),\mathcal G) \to \mathrm{Fun}(S,\mathcal G) \,,
$$
where $\mathrm{Fun}^\otimes(-,-)$ denotes the category of symmetric monoidal functors and (symmetric) monoidal natural transformations between symmetric monoidal categories, and $\mathrm{Fun}(-,-)$ denotes the category of functors and natural transformations between two categories (viewing $S$ as a category with no non-identity morphisms).

Let us say that $\mathcal G(S)$ (or more properly the pair $(\mathcal G(S),f)$) is a *free strict Picard groupoid* on $S$ if the above restriction functor is an equivalence for all strict Picard groupoids $\mathcal G$. Such a thing, if it exists, is essentially unique. My question is, **does the free strict Picard groupoid on $S$ exist?** My suspicion is that $\mathcal G(S)$ should be none other than the free abelian group $\mathbb Z\cdot S$ generated by $S$, viewed as a strict Picard groupoid with no non-identity morphisms. A reference, especially if my speculation is true, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a strict Picard groupoid? A symmetric-monoidal $\infty$-groupoid with a $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure on the corresponding connective spectrum? Then you'll have to take this into account on the left hand side of your equivalence. If you take all symmetric-monoidal functors your universal property should already characterize the free Picard groupoid on $S$, which is not strict.

Comment: You can take something like $\Omega^\infty \Sigma^2 H\mathbb{Z} $ as target to see that $\mathbb{Z} $ is not a free strict Picard groupoid on the one-element set in your sense.

Comment: @AchimKrause By a Picard groupoid, I mean a symmetric monoidal 1-category in which all morphisms are invertible and the functor $X\otimes(-)\colon \mathcal G\to\mathcal G$ is an equivalence for all objects $X$. By a *strict* Picard groupoid, I mean a Picard groupoid in which the commutativity constraint $\beta_{X,X}\colon X\otimes X \to X\otimes X$ is the identity for all objects $X$. These are sometimes called strictly commutative Picard groupoids.

Comment: @AchimKrause I'm not sure I follow the logic that goes from "the free Picard groupoid on $S$ is not strict" to "there is no free strict Picard groupoid on $S$". That is, because I'm requiring the universal property only for $\mathcal G$ *strict*, it is not automatic that a free strict Picard groupoid would be a free Picard groupoid, or vice versa. (I wasn't clear in the question that $\mathcal G$ should be assumed strict; I'll clarify that now). Put another way, I believe that $\Omega^\infty\Sigma^2H\mathbb Z$ is not strict, so doesn't give a counterexample to $\mathbb Z$ being free strict.

Comment: @AchimKrause By way of analogy, consider the "free abelian group" functor, from {sets} to {abelian groups}. The free abelian group $F_{ab}(S)$ on a set $S$ is characterised by the fact that $\mathrm{Hom}(F_{ab}(S),G)\to\mathrm{Map}(S,G)$ is an isomorphism for all abelian groups $G$. The free group $F(S)$ on $S$ also satisfies this same universal property, but this does not imply that $F(S)=F_{ab}(S)$ in general, exactly because $F(S)$ can be non-abelian. I could envisage something similar happening with strict vs. non-strict Picard groupoids.

Comment: Ah, you're in $1$-categories, sorry! Yes, then the strict Picard groupoids form in fact a full subcategory of all Picard groupoids, and the free objects should be as you say. Another way to express this is that $\operatorname{Fun}^\otimes(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{G})$ agrees with the full subcategory of $\mathcal{G}$ on strict objects. I'm afraid I don't know a reference (and the argument I have in mind works by exhibiting both as full subcategories of connective spectra)